# Updating a field in a table from a form using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form named "Form1" and it has a Textbox named "Test" i would like to update the table "tbl_Room" in the field of "RoomNoOccupant" using vba. what would be the code for updating the field. thanks...

Comment: Why not bind the table you wish to update?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open connection to your database. If the databse were local database (from mdb itself), after that just use some standard SQL query

```
Dim con as new ADODB.Connection
Set con = CurrentProject.Connection

con.execute"UPDATE tbl_Room SET RoomNoOccupant = '" & test & "' " & _
           "WHERE RoomCode = " & Emp_Room  & ";"
```

Comment: yes sir... the database is a local. just wondering what if i have condition like update only if the "RoomCode" (Primary Key) from the table is equal to Emp_Room from the form then it will update the RoomNoOccupant in the table with the same primary key?

Comment: I edited my answer above. Basically, you have to run simple UPDATE SQL query and put the WHERE clause with the value form.